# Use user input for switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

For my Java class, we have to detect user input of a Pokemon ability and give an output of the description of said ability using a Switch. I have the scanner to detect an input, but when I type anything other than the case numbers then it just gives me an error. I don't know how to make it detect an ability like 'Chlorophyll,' and then have it use the output to the console.

Here is my code:

```
package pokemonAbility;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PokemonAbility {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter Pokemon ability:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int abilityPkmn = scanner.nextInt();
    String abilityString;
    switch (abilityPkmn) {
    case 1: abilityString = "Chlorophyll";
        System.out.println("Boosts the Pokémon's Speed stat in harsh sunlight.");
        break;
    case 2: abilityString = "Guts";
        System.out.println("Boosts the Pokemon's Attack stat when it has a status condition.");
        break;
    case 3: abilityString = "Cacophony";
        System.out.println("The Pokemon is immune to sound-based moves.");
        break;
    case 4: abilityString = "Damp";
        System.out.println("Prevents the use of Explosion and Self-Destruct.");
        break;
    case 5: abilityString = "Drought";
        System.out.println("Activates harsh sunlight when the Pokémon enters battle.");
        break;
    default: abilityString = "Invalid ability";
        break;

    }
    
}
```

Comment: What did you type is it numbers or strings?

Comment: It is better, if you also add the error message in your question. From your question, it looks like from 1 to 5 input works fine, as long as you do not add space before or after. if it is over 5 then you will not get error but you will also not see any result. If you input anything other than number, including fraction, you will get exception.

Comment: `int abilityPkmn = scanner.nextInt();` why do you think it would accept anything than `int` ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  If I understand correctly, your post seems to say: "I wrote a program that accepts integers.  I don't understand how to make it accept strings.  Please write my code for me."  I'm sorry, but that's not how this works.  We are here to answer questions when you get *stuck*, not write *your code* for you.  If you try writing a program that accepts strings, and run into an issue, then that is the time to post to Stack Overflow.  Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter Pokemon ability:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String abilityPkmn = scanner.next(); //here no int because u are taking string 
    String abilityString; //u do not need this anymore!
    switch (abilityPkmn) {
    case "Chlorophyll":
        System.out.println("Boosts the Pokémon's Speed stat in harsh sunlight.");
        break;
    case "Guts":
        System.out.println("Boosts the Pokemon's Attack stat when it has a status condition.");
        break;
    case "Cacophony":
        System.out.println("The Pokemon is immune to sound-based moves.");
        break;
    case "Damp":
        System.out.println("Prevents the use of Explosion and Self-Destruct.");
        break;
    case "Drought":
        System.out.println("Activates harsh sunlight when the Pokémon enters battle.");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("here comes any default text which is not included in all cases and there is no need for break;");

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you will need to identify these variables and then write in the code or action performed in a new statement.

Try putting the statements into an array then call them in a method.

Perhaps set up a new class called abilities and create some values. When you call them in a new method you can super class those abilities.

IvonH on gitHub you can see what I have done for a simple army game.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed that you haven't used the print statement in the default case. Use the println statement to get the output on the standard output device.

vote my answer if this helps.